# How to reattach Fragment (fragment Not not attached to an activity Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm getting frustrated with this error Fragment not attached to an activity, I have a fragment that starts an activity and activity starts another activity so on and so forth `F -> A1 -> A2 -> A3`, after I finished with the last one `A3` I call to go back to the hosted activity

```
val intent = Intent(applicationContext, TabbarActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("finish", "true")
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK.or(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
```

but when I set `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` it disattached my fragment from the activity and then i get this error `Fragment not attached to an activity`, every thing will work fine if i rerun my app.

here is the host Activity

```
private var bottomNavigation: BottomNavigationView? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabbar)


        val finish = intent.getStringExtra("finish")

        bottomNavigation = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView)
        val navigationController = findNavController(R.id.fragment)

        bottomNavigation?.setupWithNavController(navigationController)
        bottomNavigation?.itemIconTintList = null


        val firstFragment: Fragment = Fragment1()
        val secondFragment: Fragment = Fragment2()
        val thirdFragment: Fragment = Fragment3()
        val forthFragment: Fragment = Fragment4()
        var active = firstFragment


        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.containerb, forthFragment, "4").hide(forthFragment).commit()
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.containerb, thirdFragment, "3").hide(thirdFragment).commit()
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.containerb, secondFragment, "2").hide(secondFragment).commit()
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.containerb, firstFragment, "1").commit()

        if (finish.equals("true")){

            bottomNavigation?.setSelectedItemId(R.id.ordersFragment);
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(thirdFragment).commit()
            active = thirdFragment
        }


        bottomNavigation?.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener {
            when (it.itemId) {
                R.id.Fragment1 -> {
                    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(firstFragment).commit()
                    active = firstFragment

                }
                R.id.Fragment2 -> {
                    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(secondFragment).commit()
                    active = secondFragment

                }
                R.id.Fragment3 -> {
                    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(thirdFragment).commit()
                    active = thirdFragment

                }
                R.id.Fragment4 -> {
                    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(forthFragment).commit()
                    active = forthFragment

                }
            }
            true
        }


        bottomNavigation?.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
            when (item.itemId) {
                R.id.Fragment1 -> {
                    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(firstFragment).commit()
                    active = firstFragment

                }
                R.id.Fragment2 -> {
                    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(secondFragment).commit()
                    active = secondFragment
                }
                R.id.Fragment3 -> {
                    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(thirdFragment).commit()
                    active = thirdFragment
                }
                R.id.Fragment4 -> {
                    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(forthFragment).commit()
                    active = forthFragment
                }
            }
            true
        }

    }
```

***when im getting this error?***

after finish with the last activity and the user navigate back user can receive a notification the error starts with this method when the notification request a context i have tried `requireContext(), this@..Activity, applicationContext, activity.context`, and all the possibilities to get the context Here is the Fragment3

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        createNotificationChannele()
}
private fun newOrderOffers() {
        val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid ?: ""
        val firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        val fireRef = firestore.collection("inProcess").whereEqualTo("userUid", uid)
        fireRef.addSnapshotListener { value, error ->
            if (value != null) {
                value.documentChanges.forEach {
                    if (it.type == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {

                        SendNotificationWhenSelected()

                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

private fun createNotificationChannele(){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            val channel = NotificationChannel(chanal_id, chanale_name,
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH).apply {
                lightColor = Color.RED
                enableLights(true)
            }
            val manager = this.context?.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }

    }
private fun SendNotificationWhenSelected(){
        val notification =
            NotificationCompat.Builder(requireContext(), chanal_id) // the error in this line
                .setContentTitle("...")
                .setContentText("....")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.....)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .build()

        val notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(requireView().context)
        notificationManager.notify(notification_id, notification)
}
```

the logcat error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment Fragment3{3131d71} (ee9f090f-fa37-46a0-9fda-b7e9831db10d)} not attached to an activity.
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.requireActivity(Fragment.java:833)
        at com.qp.dele.fragment.Fragment3.SendNotificationWhenSelected(3Fragment.kt:295)
        at com.qp.dele.fragment.Fragment3.access$SendNotificationWhenSelected(Fragment3.kt:40)
        at com.qp.dele.fragment.Fragment3$newOrderOffers$1.onEvent(Fragment3.kt:272)
        at com.qp.dele.fragment.Fragment3$newOrderOffers$1.onEvent(Fragment3.kt:40)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.Query.lambda$addSnapshotListenerInternal$2(Query.java:1133)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.Query$$Lambda$3.onEvent(Unknown Source:6)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.AsyncEventListener.lambda$onEvent$0(AsyncEventListener.java:42)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.AsyncEventListener$$Lambda$1.run(Unknown Source:6)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and post the complete error message with stacktrace from logcat.

Comment: In your first run does fragment 3 run into the loop to send a notification? Do  SendNotificationWhenSelected() trigger on the first run or only when you finished and return to the start where you get the error?

Comment: `newOrderOffers()` is being called and generating the exception. Where is that called from?

Comment: it's called in fragment3 onCreatedView() method

Comment: Is there a reason why you are clearing the task stack (using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` and creating a new instance of the `Activity` instead of just returning to the existing instance?

Comment: it does trigger on the first run of the app @DominikWuttke

Comment: yes, so the user cannot get back to the same stack its like a post if you want to create one you have to fill all the information again, and if i didnt clear the stack and the fragment will keep stacking forever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that the old `Fragment` is still there and is still getting the Firebase callback after it has been detached from the old `Activity`. You'll need to remove the Firebase callbacks when the old `Fragment` is detached/destroyed.

This is why you see this problem when you return back to `TabbarActivity` but not when you start the app for the first time.

Comment: This doesn't sounds relevant to this question. You should post another question with details of this problem

Comment: thanks so much, I just removed the callback on detached/destroyed works fine now, I have been searching all over the internet since last night I just wasted so much time on this, knowing the problem is the solution, thanks again.